# how to merge numbers from one column into the second column to create a unique numeric value

Tags: r, matrix, merge, rscript

I am trying to merge the ID in column one with the numbers in column two, to create the unique ID. Here is what I start off with

```
1002   1    2
1002   2    0
1002   3    0
1003   1    1
1003   4    0
1003   2    1
1004   3    0
```

> Here is what I'm trying to achieve

```
1002   1002.1    2
1002   1002.2    0
1002   1002.3    0
1003   1003.1    1
1003   1003.4    0
1003   1003.2    1
1004   1004.3    0
```

and here is my  attempt

```
data = matrix(scan("file.txt", what = "", sep = ""), ncol = 3, byrow = T)
data = matrix(paste(data[,1], data[,2], sep = "."), ncol = 1, byrow = T)
```

Comment: `tidyr::unite(df, V1_V2, V1, V2)`

Comment: @alistaire this works however, a period is needed and not the underscore..thanks!

Comment: `tidyr::unite(df, V1.V2, V1, V2, sep = '.')`

Answer (score 0):

Given the following data

```
df <- data.frame(
    x = c(1002, 1002, 1002, 1003, 1003, 1003, 1004),
    y = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 2, 3),
    z = c(2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0)
)
print(df)

##      x y z
## 1 1002 1 2
## 2 1002 2 0
## 3 1002 3 0
## 4 1003 1 1
## 5 1003 4 0
## 6 1003 2 1
## 7 1004 3 0
```

You can use `transform` and `paste0` to do the following

```
df <- transform(df, y = paste0(x, ".",y))
print(df)
##      x      y z
## 1 1002 1002.1 2
## 2 1002 1002.2 0
## 3 1002 1002.3 0
## 4 1003 1003.1 1
## 5 1003 1003.4 0
## 6 1003 1003.2 1
## 7 1004 1004.3 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this simply (assuming that you have 3 columns in the dataframe df):

```
cbind.data.frame(ID=paste(df[,1], df[,2], sep='.'), Val=df[,3])

      ID Val
1 1002.1   2
2 1002.2   0
3 1002.3   0
4 1003.1   1
5 1003.4   0
6 1003.2   1
7 1004.3   0
```